# ASP.NET beginner question regarding reference path

Tags: asp.net

I want to know what "<% =QDAB.Constants.SiteURL %>"  means in the following line of code in my aspx page. I did google and didn't really find any information on this.

```
<td align="center" style="background-image: url(<% =QDAB.Constants.SiteURL %>images/Docs/Plans/myImage.jpg);
```

So what exactly does this mean?

[Aditional Details]

I changed `url(<% =QDAB.Constants.SiteURL %>images/Docs/Plans/myImage.jpg);`

to this `url(<% =QDAB.Constants.SiteURL %>images/myImage.jpg);`

I copied myImage in the "Images" folder.

Why would it access the image from "Images" folder BUT NOT "Images/Docs/Plans"?

This is so weird.

Comment: I would suggest you to try to see in firebug if request for image (.../docs/plans/myimage.jpg) is made or not, and if it was successful or not. Could happen that the access rights are not the same on "images" and "images/docs/plans" directory.

Comment: How do you check that in firebug ? sry I am new to .net..Also How do I check the permissions on "images/docs/plans" directory ??

Comment: How about you just enter the complete URL formed by <% =QDAB.Constants.SiteURL %>images/Docs/Plans/myImage.jpg in the address bar of your browser, press enter and see if the image show up or do you see any error? If error, what error do you get?

Comment: @happysoul: There is really a lot of information in the provided answers and comments so there is no need to ask the same question again. Have you already searched your code for the class QDAB? Have you checked the source of your rendered page to see what's actually there? I now see that there is a space between <% and =. I'm not sure if that works, but maybe you can change it to <%= QDAB...etc.

Comment: have sorted out the problem..it was some problem with the path..there are two copies of the project in diff drives..whats funny is ..inside VS..the project path shows as F:/ blah blah BUT inside IIS its G:/ blah blah..I mean both should show SAME address..isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that there is a constant variable defined in QDAB.Constants class called SiteURL.

Most likely it is something of the sort "www.xyz.com/"

Using the <% = variable Name %>, the value of the variable is used in the HTML

What

```
url(<% =QDAB.Constants.SiteURL %>images/Docs/Plans/myImage.jpg);
```

hence does is using the variable value, it concatenates it with the rest of the string creating a complete URL of the type

```
url(www.xyz.com/images/Docs/Plans/myImage.jpg);
```

which is where the image used to set the background of this HTML tag is going to be located

Comment: this thing <% =QDAB.Constants.SiteURL %> is actually not working..i had to give "../../images" instead of this..only then the back ground image is appearing...this TD tag is actually a part of some master1.master file..there is this another master2.master file that is using "<% =QDAB.Constants.SiteURL %>"  only and the SAME image appears

Comment: Since Master2 is able to get the value, that means that it is part of your project. Can you do a "Go to Definition" from Master2 file and see where this class is? It could be possible that some reference / using statement is all that is missing in this Master file causing it to not be able to resolve this variable

Comment: I checked the using statements.they are the same in both the master files

Comment: @happysoul, Master1 may have used @Import directive (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack.aspx). Use same directive in your second master page. @Import directive is equivalent of using <namespace> syntax in markup side (aspx).

Comment: @Vinay there are no import statements in both the master files

Comment: this expression or whatever "<% =QDAB.Constants.SiteURL %>" has also been used to refer to .css files and .js files in both he master page files..  BOTH css and JS are applying well in master1.master as wel as master2.master...the only problem is that in Master1.master this thing "<% =QDAB.Constants.SiteURL %>" doesn't work when used to refer images..why is that so ? Why would it work with css and js but not images???

Comment: ok I just tried something... plz check the additional details in the ques n someone help me! :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is referencing a server variable: QDAB.Constants.SiteURL

Try searching through your code for QDAB (It's probably a class)

The <% = blah %> gets the value of blah variable.

Comment: @happysoul: As others had said, can you take the url result of url(<% =QDAB.Constants.SiteURL %>images/myImage.jpg); and modify the url in your browser to ../images/Docs/Plans/myImage.jpg and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how well Intellisense works in your platform, but this means that there is probably a static property on a Constants static class or a Constants property on the QDAB class. Try right clicking SiteURL and click on Go to definition (or something similar).

As to why someone would do this, they want the url of the background image to be dynamic.